# Devise User registration validation based on role

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am new to Rails and programming in general. I am using Devise for registration and have a User model with two roles: project_manager and sales.

Upon registration, if a user selects project_manager, I would like registration to continue as usual. If sales is selected, I need to check the email domain against a whitelist.

Initially I was able to get this working using two separate models for devise and validating the email format of the Sales model with:

`validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@(company\.com)|(work\.com)\z/`

I cannot figure out how to run this validation based on a selected role before a user record is created.

Comment: Please share the model details. Do you have a separate model for Roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@(company|work)\.com\z/i }, if: ->(user) { user.role == 'sale' }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. So simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@(company\.com)|(work\.com)\z/, if: ->{ |user| user.role == 'sale' }
```